# Questions about AWS auto scaling and load balancing

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have little bit knowledge of `AWS EC2`. Previously I have bought a `mx3large` instance and did all my necessary installations on the server and cloned my code there but didn't map domain to the system.

Now my client wants to implement auto scalling and load balancing. I have read about those that auto scalling is to add/subtract instances with respect to traffic and load balancing is to balance loads between instances.First correct me if I am wrong.

Now I want to ask

1. If I auto scale some instances, do I need to do installations on all instances or some one instance? If one then what will be my primary instance?
2. As mentioned above, I have already bought an instance where I did my all installations. But that instance is currently stop. Will I remove that instance when I will be using auto scaling?
3. What are the prices. If I bought a instance of $0.28/hour, will I have to pay number of instances * cost for number of time they are activated?
4. On which instance I will be cloning my code, ssh to connect and all related operations?
5. Load balancing will automatically start working with my auto scall instances?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ServerFault isn't a replacement for reading the AWS documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> If I auto scale some instances, do I need to do installations on all
>   instances or some one instance? If one then what will be my primary
>   instance?

There is no such thing as a "primary instance". When you set up an ASG, you specify which AMI you want to use for the ASG instances. You can either bake your application and configuration into that AMI, or you can have them configure themselves after boot. It's up to you on how you want to handle this.

> As mentioned above, I have already bought an instance where I did my
>   all installations. But that instance is currently stop. Will I remove
>   that instance when I will be using auto scaling?

If you want to do so, sure.

> What are the prices. If I bought a instance of $0.28/hour, will I have
>   to pay number of instances * cost for number of time they are
>   activated?

Whether or not an instance is "standalone" or part of an ASG does not affect its cost.

> On which instance I will be cloning my code, ssh to connect and all
>   related operations?

See the answer to your first question above. Generally, you don't make any modifications to ASG instances. If you need to deploy new code, you either bake a new AMI, which gets used to instantiate new ASG instances, or you modify your post-boot deployment scripts to deploy the new code.

> Load balancing will automatically start working with my auto scall
>   instances?

If configured correctly, yes.